# Is Watching any dramas in free time permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sharia, women, sin

Assalamu Alaikum. I usually watch movies or series in my free time. I mean after maghrib and I try maintain my prayer time. Is it permissible for women to watch Pakistani dramas or kdramas. They don’t wear hijab in the dramas but they are in normal clothes. And I am not involving any bad things or have any intention. It just for my free time entainment. Should completely stop watching ? Or is it fine to watch in my free time after I’m done with everything ? Also is it permissible to watch any film that contains some types of sexual content with husband ? Because recently I came across with this Hadith and I am confused Ibn Maajah (4245) narrated from Thawbaan (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “I certainly know people of my ummah who will come on the Day of Resurrection with good deeds like the mountains of Tihaamah, but Allaah will make them like scattered dust. and I am concerned what this Hadith exactly meant. did it mean about masturbation or porn or this kind of movies too.